# what is the sequence of commands to send out review in Bit Bucket?

Tags: git, github

```
Step1:git checkout master
Step2:git pull
Step3:<Make changes>>
Step4:git add *
Step5:git checkout feature
Step6:git commit -m "test"
Step7:git merge --no-ff origin master
Step8:git push
```

Sometimes after step 4, i am able to checkout feature branch..

Sometimes i am getting "`Please, commit your changes.`." and If I commit master then only it is switching to feature branch.

Sometimes After Step 7, i can go ahead for push and some times it is giving below message

```
fatal: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you merge.
```

Sometimes After step 8, i can submit pull requests for Review it is success. Some cases i am getting `"Please rebase your branch on to the target branch before creating a pull request: git checkout feature; git rebase master; git push -f"`

I wanted to know why for test same set of action, results are different.

Can any one explain the sequence of steps that i am following is correct?

Comment: The steps are glossing over a lot of facts. First, you already must have a branch named "feature", otherwise step 5 won't work. Secondly, if the files you've changed in step 3 are also different between master and feature, you can't checkout feature since this should replace those files and they have been altered. Thirdly, the merge in step 7 produces a merge conflict, you need to resolve this. So yes, the steps *look* good, but if your assumptions are wrong you will need more steps.

Comment: 1. I have feature branch before step5. 2) After pulling from master, if I checkout feature and make changes will it over come "Please, commit your changes." after Step 4. 3) After conflicts resolved, do I need to commit again to push it for feature branch. Can you please clear that?